# What does the inflating step do during django deployment on elastic beanstalk and where are the files coming from?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently debugging a deployment of a Django 1.11 application to AWS elastic beanstalk. The eb-activity.log specifies the following:

```
gc3df-181026_105229@80/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/02unzip.py] : Completed activity. Result:
  Archive:  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
  c3df867f3af443a2c832b8a9071c9867b199f522
```

It then creates and inflates a bunch of files, excerpt:

```
creating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0001_initial.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0002_auto_20180729_1449.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0003_auto_20180729_1651.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0004_auto_20180805_1744.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0005_auto_20180805_2051.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0006_auto_20180806_2028.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0007_profile_interactive_gram.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0008_auto_20180911_0925.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0009_auto_20180917_1753.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0010_auto_20180918_2247.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0011_profile_email_verified.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0012_auto_20181025_1155.py  
    inflating: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/0013_auto_20181025_2242.py  
   extracting: /opt/python/ondeck/app/grams/migrations/__init__.py
```

My questions are:

1. Where is the ondeck folder? Is it temporary? I do not see it when poking around the server via ssh
2. What is inflating?
3. Where are these migration files coming from? I have specifically deleted migration files from my project and the server, save a single migration file in the code base that I am deploying. This is an old set of migration files listed?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should probably assume that the "ondeck" folder is temporary and being cleaned up during the AppDeployPreHook phase.
2. Inflating/Deflating is actually just a compression algorithm used by zip
3. If you deleted the migration files then they shouldn't be in the archive, so the answer to this depends on a few factors:  How are you packaging your source code?  Are you perhaps appending to an existing zip archive?  This would add new files but wouldn't delete files from the archive, so you could try deleting your .zip archive and recreating it.